# How to prevent user to go to login page after logged in in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

After the user is logged in i dont want the user to access the log in page. I have tried this one down below but it's seem like it's not working. What should I do to make it works?

**[Updated]**

When I `console.log(store.getters.loggedIn` inside `else if` statement it returns false so I think the problem maybe is with `store.getters`. Since I'm a beginner in Vuejs I'm really not sure how to fix it. I will add my vuex code down below. Hope I can get some helps.

Thanks before hand!

```
// vuex
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    accessToken: null,
    refreshToken: null,
    APIData: "",
  },
  mutations: {
    updateStorage(state, { access, refresh }) {
      state.accessToken = access;
      state.refreshToken = refresh;
    },
    destroyToken(state) {
      state.accessToken = null;
      state.refreshToken = null;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    loggedIn(state) {
      return state.accessToken != null;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    userLogout(context) {
      console.log("hello");
      if (context.getters.loggedIn) {
        context.commit("destroyToken");
      }
    },
    userLogin(context, usercredentials) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAPI
          .post("/rest-api-token/", {
            email: usercredentials.email,
            password: usercredentials.password,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            context.commit("updateStorage", {
              access: response.data.access,
              refresh: response.data.refresh,
            });
            resolve();
            console.log(this.getters.loggedIn); <-- return true
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    },
  },
  modules: {},
});

// main.js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresLogin)) {
    if (!store.getters.loggedIn) {
      next({ name: "login" });
    } 
    else {
      next();
    }
  } 
  // if user is logged in and go to log in page redirect them to home page
  else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
    if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
      next({ name: 'home'});
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
  }
  // 
  else {
    next();
  }
});

//index.js (router)
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "login",
    component: Login,
    meta: {
      requiresVisitor: true,
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/home",
    name: "home",
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      requiresLogin: true,
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/logout",
    name: "logout",
    component: Logout,
  },
];
```

Comment: This looks kinda consistent. Did you debug those values, maybe there is some issue with your store.getters?

Comment: I put console.log(store.getters.loggedIn) into `else if` statement and it returns false :(

Comment: so is it solved?

Comment: No it is not solved yet

Comment: ok let me rephrase it ;) your current question is: why is `store.getters.loggedIn` false, isnt it? As the code above should work if otherwise?

Comment: yes you're right i think the problem is on `store.getters.loggedIn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would add a state in my store called:

```js
state: {
    accessToken: null,
    refreshToken: null,
    APIData: "",
    loggedIn: false //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
  },
```

then i would add a mutation for the Login Process, if the User Loggedin successfully

```js
mutations: {
    updateStorage(state, { access, refresh }) {
      state.accessToken = access;
      state.refreshToken = refresh;
    },
    destroyToken(state) {
      state.accessToken = null;
      state.refreshToken = null;
    },
    loginAttempt(state, payload) { //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<HERE
      state.loggedIn = payload
    }

  },
```

and toggle the login state to true if success or false if failed.

then i add a v-if="userIsLoggedIn" in your login component and be toggle the Login if user is not logged in and show  the Login Component or hide it

---

of course the `userIsLoggedIn` should be a computed:

```js
computed: {
  userIsLoggedIn: function() {
    return this.$store.state.loggedIn
  }
}
```